# Stotra for improving self-confidence, self esteem and overcoming anxitey

Tags: mantras

I'm facing some issue with my self-confidence, anxiety and self esteem. Which slokas  is help to overcome this issue? Is Aditya Hridaya stotra really work?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, aditya hridayam is a very well known and effective stotra relared to lord Surya or Sun. As per the legend this stotra was done by lord Rama to achive victory in his battle with rAvana.

> [[3-5](http://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/ADITYA.PDF)]: Rama,  O  mighty-armed  Sri Rama,    hearken    to    the    following eternal  secret,  in  the  form  of  a  holy, eternal,    **immortal    and    supremely**
>   blessed    and    excellent    encomium, entitled   the **Aditya   Hridaya**,   the
>   blessing of all blessings, by means of which,  my  child,  You  will  conquer
>   once  for  all  Your  adversaries  on  the battlefield,  and  which  is  calculated  to bring  victory,  root  out  all  sins,  **allay all  anxiety  and  grief  once**  for  all  and prolong life.

As per astrology also surya is the significator for will power and soul. So sun worship is believed to improve will power and confidence. It is also useful for health and career related issues.

[Aditya hridaya stotra text](http://aumamen.com/stotra/aditya-hridayam-stotram)

[Aditya hridaya audio](https://youtu.be/tVD-le4uYbw)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Aditya Hridayam is good. It helps to overcome enemies. It should be recited thrice daily for a better effect.

Also try to chant Saraswati beejmantra 
' Aim ' ,10 roseries a day. It creates vibrations in neurons and improves intellect which in turn helps in getting success for an individual and success is a fuel to self esteem and self confidence.

Hope it helped! Thanks... :)