# Verse Describing Potential of Soul and Human Body in Sanskrit?

Tags: mantras, brahman, atma, sanskrit, shloka

- Is there Any song, shloka, mantra, stotra in Sanskrit,   Tell Us
  About the Powers of our Soul, Greatness of it.
- Tell Us About Our Potential,
  Powers of this human body, the amazing abilities of soul, which fills us with Confidence, Motivates Us..etc

Song Mantra Shloka(any verse) Dedicated and speaks about Us, Humans, Our Souls..

```
    Example: 
        Our deepest fear is not that we are inadequate. 
        Our deepest fear is that we are powerful beyond measure. 
        It is our light, not our darkness that most frightens us
    The Kingdom of God in within man, not one man, nor a group of men, 
    but in all men, in you, you the people have the power!”
```

I was Just watching Motivating Videos in Youtube.. In Video they were describing the powers, potential of soul, potential of Human Body. The example given in Question is from the Video.. Then I thought if there is any such shloka/verse/song in Sanskrit, Describing potential, and greatness of Human Body and Soul.. Like there is Hanuman Chalisa, to describe the Potential of Hanuman..similar for a soul, human body potential.

Comment: Something is motivating for someone something else for others. So it's subjective. Your question will be closed as "opinion based" unless you fix it :)

Comment: How do I fix it... Just asking for Sanskrit song, Verses on Potentials of Soul.. Potential of Human Body

Comment: You can avoid the word "most" at least. also I think it's better to ask about Stotras instead of songs.

Comment: I was Just watching Motivating Videos in Youtube.. In Video they were describing the powers, potential of soul, potential of Human Body, Atma.. The example given in Question is from the Video.. Then I thought if there is any such song/verse/shloka in Sanskrit, Describing potential, and greatness of Human Body and Soul.. Like there is Hanuman Chalisa, to describe the Potential of Hanuman..similar for a soul, human body capabilities

Comment: Ok good I suggested you to edit because I saw that 2 close votes are already there on the question.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks..Currently Im Learning Sanskrit, and Im a Student.. and these type Sanskrit song will help me.

Comment: This is a dup of [Stotra for improving self-confidence, self esteem and overcoming anxitey](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26851/stotra-for-improving-self-confidence-self-esteem-and-overcoming-anxitey).

Comment: @sv. Its Not.. Aditya Hradyam is About Surya God.. please Look in examples, and question body..and the comment I made..

Comment: Title of both questions is similar. Call it self-confidence or motivation, it's all the same.

Comment: it is wrong to say '**our** soul' or '**my** soul'. you should only say 'our body', or 'my body'.

Comment: @ram Body is like Cloth worn by Soul.. [Right](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/22)?? 
In this question Im asking Potential of Both.. Potential of Soul, / , Potential of Human Body.

Comment: @Rickross Potential of Soul

Comment: @HinduKid Okay ..

Answer (score 2):

This is from Rigved. I find this enthralling and motivating especially when I listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVHlhM8Gc2A&t=27s) after reading its meaning.

> **संगच्छध्वम् संवद्धवम् संवोमनाँसि जानताम् ।**
>
> **देवाभागम् यथापूर्वे सञ्जानानम् उपासते ।।**
>
> May we march forward with a common goal.
>
> May we be open-minded and work together in harmony.
>
> May we share our thoughts for integrated wisdom.
>
> May we follow the example of our ancestors who achieved higher goals
> by virtue of being united.

> **समानो मन्त्र: समिति: समानी**
>
> **समानं मन: सहचित्तमेषाम्**
>
> **समानं मन्त्रमभिमन्त्रये व:**
>
> **समानेन वो हविषा जुहोमि ।।**
>
> May our prayers be one.
>
> May we belong to one brotherhood.
>
> ay our hearts and minds move toward one supreme goal.
>
> May we be inspired by common ideals.

> **समानी व आकूति: समाना ह्र्दयानी व: ।**
>
> **समानमस्तु वो मनो यथा व: सुसहासति ।।**
>
> May our aspirations be harmonious.
>
> May our minds be in unison.
>
> May we strive to reduce disparity.
>
> May we be bound in strong fellowship and unity.

Comment: This is called the *aikyamatyasuktam* —the final hymn in the *Rigvedam*.

Answer (score 2):

This shloka gives general motivation and support and can be applied to any situation in anybody's life.

Bhagavad Gita 6.5:

> उद्धरेदात्मनात्मानं नात्मानमवसादयेत् । आत्मैव ह्यात्मनो बन्धुरात्मैव रिपुरात्मनः ॥
> One should lift up oneself by oneself. One should not let oneself get depressed or defeated - because the self is the friend of oneself and the self is the enemy of oneself.

This is a great example of brutally honest and realistic self-motivation found in the Gita. Every time I feel a bit disinterested or less motivated to carry on, I remember this shloka and gather myself up and summon the enthusiasm for everything I do. Everyone will have experienced moments of disinterest and lack of motivation. There is no magic pill to come out of it except by yourself through yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of inspiring verses.

> gayanti Deva: kila gitakanti dhanyastu ye bharatabhumibhage
> swargapebargasye phalarjanya  bhabhanti bhuyo purusha suratwat
>
> It seems that the gods sing songs to this purport. Those who live in
> this part of the world called Bharata are in fact blessed. In order to
> enjoy the fruits of heaven and salvation they are born as human
> beings, casting off their deity-hood.

**Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda Chapter 1**

> ma vo ghnatam ma sapatam prati voce deva yantam
>
> Return not blow for blow, nor curse for curse, neither meanness for
> base tricks. Shower blessings instead.

**Rig Veda 1.41.8 translated by Swami Harshananda**

Answer (score 1):

As someone already pointed, a hymn or verse or mantra motivating for someone might not work for another because of subjective difference. Anyways, some of the popular compositions of Vedanta and spirituality are:

1. [Nirvana Shatakam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FZFvFWztOA) by Adi Shankaracharya

> मनो बुद्ध्यहंकारचित्तानि नाहम् न च श्रोत्र जिह्वे न च घ्राण नेत्रे न च
> व्योम भूमिर् न तेजो न वायु: चिदानन्द रूप: शिवोऽहम् शिवोऽहम् ॥१॥
>
> I am not the mind, the intellect, the ego or the memory, I am not the
> ears, the skin, the nose or the eyes, I am not space, not earth, not
> fire, water or wind, I am the form of consciousness and bliss, I am
> the eternal Shiva...
>
> न मृत्युर् न शंका न मे जातिभेद:  पिता नैव मे नैव माता न जन्म न बन्धुर्
> न मित्रं गुरुर्नैव शिष्य:  चिदानन्द रूप: शिवोऽहम् शिवोऽहम् ॥५॥
>
> I have no fear of death, no caste or creed, I have no father, no
> mother, for I was never born, I am not a relative, nor a friend, nor a
> teacher nor a student, I am the form of consciousness and bliss, I am
> the eternal Shiva...
>
> अहं निर्विकल्पॊ निराकार रूपॊ  विभुत्वाच्च सर्वत्र सर्वेन्द्रियाणाम् न
> चासंगतं नैव मुक्तिर् न मेय:  चिदानन्द रूप: शिवोऽहम् शिवोऽहम् ॥६॥
>
> I am devoid of duality, my form is formlessness, I exist everywhere,
> pervading all senses, I am neither attached, neither free nor captive,
> I am the form of consciousness and bliss, I am the eternal Shiva...

2. [Om Purnamadah Purnamidam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5I9ZETL9xI)  - Isha Upanishad

> ॐ पूर्णमदः पूर्णमिदं पूर्णात्पूर्णमुदच्यते । पूर्णस्य पूर्णमादाय
> पूर्णमेवावशिष्यते ॥ ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः ॥
>
> Meaning: 1: Om, That (Outer World) is Purna (Full with Divine
> Consciousness); This (Inner World) is also Purna (Full with Divine
> Consciousness); From Purna is manifested Purna (From the Fullness of
> Divine Consciousness the World is manifested), 2: Taking Purna from
> Purna, Purna indeed remains (Because Divine Consciousness is Non-Dual
> and Infinite), 3: Om, Peace, Peace, Peace.

3. [Om Asato Ma Sadgamaya](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwyo62x9yC4) or [Pavamana_Mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavamana_Mantra)

> ॐ असतो मा सद्गमय । तमसो मा ज्योतिर्गमय । मृत्योर्मा अमृतं गमय । ॐ
> शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः ॥
>
> 1: Om, (O Lord) Keep me not in (the Phenomenal World of) Unreality,
> but make me go towards the Reality (of Eternal Self), 2: Keep me not
> in (the Ignorant State of) Darkness, but make me go towards the Light
> (of Spiritual Knowledge), 3: Keep me not in (the World of) Mortality,
> but make me go towards the World of Immortality (of Self-Realization),
> 4: Om, Peace, Peace, Peace.

4. [Ek Omkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ik_Onkar)

Note that most of the popular motivating verses of Vedanta end in 'Om shanti' as they are not talking about environmental peace but the mental peace of mind which is already overloaded with thoughts of world, which a listener should experience after separating real Self from the bondage of mind and world. And once a jiva silences mind, he/she automatically is one with Atman, the source of  fearlessness, intelligence, powers and bliss.

Answer (score 1):

Markandeya Purana, Canto 25 to 30,
The story is that of Madalasa who was a Self realised Queen who gave birth to a child. When the child cried, instead of diverting the child's attention with various objects she chose to introduce him to the truth. And that truth is sung in the form of a sweet lullaby which is called madalasa upadesha or madalasa putra upadesha.

https://practicalphilosophy.org.au/extras/mada-lasa/

शुद्धोसि बुद्धोसि निरँजनोऽसि
सँसारमाया परिवर्जितोऽसि
सँसारस्वप्नँ त्यज मोहनिद्राँ
मँदालसोल्लपमुवाच पुत्रम्।

Madalasa says to her crying son:
You are pure, Enlightened, and spotless.
Leave the illusion of the world
and wake up from this deep slumber of delusion.

शुद्धोऽसि रे तात न तेऽस्ति नाम
कृतँ हि तत्कल्पनयाधुनैव।
पच्चात्मकँ देहँ इदँ न तेऽस्ति
नैवास्य त्वँ रोदिषि कस्य हेतो॥

My Child, you are Ever Pure! You do not have a name. A name is only an imaginary superimposition on you.
This body made of five elements is not you nor do you belong to it. This being so, what can be a reason for your crying ?

न वै भवान् रोदिति विक्ष्वजन्मा
शब्दोयमायाध्य महीश सूनूम्।
विकल्पयमानो विविधैर्गुणैस्ते
गुणाश्च भौताः सकलेन्दियेषु॥

The essence of the universe does not cry in reality. All is a maya of words, oh Prince! Please understand this. The various qualities you seem to have are are just your imaginations, they belong to the elements that make the senses (and have nothing to do with you).

भूतनि भूतैः परिदुर्बलानि
वृद्धिँ समायाति यथेह पुँसः।
अन्नाम्बुपानादिभिरेव तस्मात्
न तेस्ति वृद्धिर् न च तेस्ति हानिः॥

The Elements [that make this body] grow with accumulation of more elements or reduce in size if some elements are taken away. This is what is seen in a body's growing in size or becoming lean depending upon the consumption of food, water etc. You do not have growth or decay.

त्वम् कँचुके शीर्यमाणे निजोस्मिन्
तस्मिन् देहे मूढताँ मा व्रजेथाः।
शुभाशुभौः कर्मभिर्देहमेतत्
मृदादिभिः कँचुकस्ते पिनद्धः॥

You are in the body which is like a jacket that gets worn out day by day. Do not have the wrong notion that you are the body. This body is like a jacket that you are tied to, for the frutification of the good and bad karmas.

तातेति किँचित् तनयेति किँचित्
अँबेति किँचिद्धयितेति किँचित्।
ममेति किँचित् न ममेति किँचित्
त्वम् भूतसँघँ बहु म नयेथाः॥

Some may refer to you are Father and some others may refer to you a Son or
some may refer to you as mother and some one else may refer to you as wife.
some say you are mine and some others say you are not mine
These are all references to this Combination of Physical Elements, Do not identify with them.

सुखानि दुःखोपशमाय भोगान्
सुखाय जानाति विमूढचेताः।
तान्येव दुःखानि पुनः सुखानि
जानाति विद्धनविमूढचेताः॥

The deluded look at objects of enjoyments as giving happiness by removing the unhappiness. The wise clearly see that the same object which gives happiness now will become a source of unhappiness.

यानँ चित्तौ तत्र गतश्च देहो
देहोपि चान्यः पुरुषो निविष्ठः।
ममत्वमुरोया न यथ तथास्मिन्
देहेति मात्रँ बत मूढरौष।

The vehicle that moves on the ground is different from the person in it similarly this body is also different from the person who is inside!
The owner of the body is different from the body! Ah how foolish it is to think I am the body!

Here is the 'link' where it has been sung beautifully

https://m.youtube.com/watch?index=10&list=RDvr_M9tc_s4Q&v=uDd3iupKUyI

Comment: Thank You..so-much.. This is Beautiful.. I was looking for something like this.. which talks about SOUL..You know any Other..